# Is there a way I can edit Eclipse's code to add some custom shortcuts, my own code completion, and some formatting stuff?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

There are a few things I want from IntelliJ, but I just can't live with it. Eclipse is better for me in more ways and I would like to add some of the IntelliJ functionality into it.

Pretty much everything I want from IntelliJ is pretty simple (just a few shortcuts), but I use them often. I just want to know if it is possible for me to add what I want.

For some of the stuff I know I can use an external script, but I rather include what I want from within Eclipse an not externally.

Comment: and... what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Plug-in development environment](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) in order to create your own Eclipse custom functionallity.
For example a [Hello world](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html) plugin.